# How to find number of corner in an image opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

in below image i am getting 70 corners but it should be 8 corners .
I am using below code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
def find_centroids(dst):
    ret, dst = cv2.threshold(dst, 0.01 * dst.max(), 255, 0)
    dst = np.uint8(dst)

    # find centroids
    ret, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(dst)
    # define the criteria to stop and refine the corners
    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 100, 
                0.001)
    corners = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,np.float32(centroids[1:]),(5,5), 
              (-1,-1),criteria)
    return corners

image = cv2.imread("hexa_bron.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gray = np.float32(gray)

dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray, 3, 3, 0.04)

dst = cv2.dilate(dst, None)

# Threshold for an optimal value, it may vary depending on the image.
# image[dst > 0.01*dst.max()] = [0, 0, 255]

# Get coordinates
corners = find_centroids(dst)
# To draw the corners
for corner in corners:
    image[int(corner[1]), int(corner[0])] = [0, 0, 255]
int_corners = np.asarray(corners, dtype = int)
print (len(int_corners))
```

image used is [image]

how to correct this so that i can get 8 corners . I have seen difference when i have used coloured images. So how to find number of corners of any kind of image using python .

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `cv2.approxPolyDP()`. This should help guide you on implementation https://theailearner.com/2019/11/22/simple-shape-detection-using-contour-approximation/

EDIT: Adding info to address the OPs modified question.

When I run your code on the image provided, I get 16 points, which is 8 for the interior contour and 8 for the exterior contour. For outlines in images, you typically get two nearly identical contours. There are a few ways you can address this to end up with 8 corner points.

Here's the original code results. You can see two points at each of the eight corners.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(gray, cmap="gray")
plt.scatter(int_corners[:, 0], int_corners[:, 1])
```

[image: original 16 points]

I went the route of averaging the coordinates of points that fall within a distance threshold of one another. You can play with this as your application necessitates.

```py
mean_corners = np.zeros_like(int_corners)

for idx, point in enumerate(int_corners):
    square_dists = np.sum((int_corners - point)**2, axis=1)
    mask = square_dists < 200    # square distance threshold
    if np.sum(mask) != 2:
        raise ValueError("Two corner points not selected")
    # average the two points
    mean_corners[idx, :] = np.mean(int_corners[mask, :], axis=0)

# keep only unique points, since there will be a duplicate for each point
unique_corners = np.unique(mean_corners, axis=0)
```

Plotting the new points with code similar to above
[image]

The output of `unique_corners` is

```
[[ 306  426]
 [ 518   60]
 [ 518  792]
 [ 866   60]
 [ 866  235]
 [ 941  792]
 [1042  235]
 [1152  426]]
```

EDIT 2:

Tinkering with this a bit more, you can also simply increase the `blockSize` parameter for the Harris corner detection. Increasing results in both interior and exterior corners to be within the same block, and return a singular corner -- no need for averaging. Here's the updated line with `blockSize` increased from 3 to 10.

```py
dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray, 10, 3, 0.04)
```

Comment: thanks for above can u suggest how to get interior and exterior angles at each corner

Comment: and while running above code provided by you i am getting error i.e ValueError: Two corner points not selected

Comment: @k_p play with the distance threshold. That error message is intentionally put in there for debug purposes. It means you are grabbing 1 or 3+ points in the accumulator. As for angles, I would need to play with it a little more. I believe `approxPolyDP` returns data in an ordered list, meaning you could do some math/geometry to calculate the angle created by 3 adjacent points. Again, I would need to confirm

Comment: if possible can u help me to find with angles at each corner point

Comment: For what it's worth, I would create a separate question/post with your angle question once you flesh out the corner algorithm. That question could address point sorting and angle calculations. Show your initial efforts and also link to this post. I am happy to help a bit later when I have more time

Comment: can u suggest how to get unique corners i am using same image but getting error i.e. ValueError: Two corner points not selected @Davis

Comment: Comment out the `raise ValueError` line. If you are truly getting 70 corners, they you want to be averaging a lot more than 2 points. For debug, plot or print the new corners to confirm you get the correct 8 points

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233459/discussion-between-k-p-and-davis).